# Curl php. Тупит сайт во время запроса

Tags: php, curl

Делаю запрос к сервису через CURL. Бывает такое, что ответ от сервиса приходит через 10-20 сек, пока нет ответа от сервиса сайт жестко тупит или вообще висеть может. Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: распределить задачи, добавить псевдо асинхронность

Comment: Возможно это проблема не сервиса, а DNS. Трассировку запроса проводили?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько критичны данные, получаемые от стороннего сервиса? Они точно необходимы для дальнейшей отработки вашего контроллера? Если это какая-то синхронизация то я бы предложил этот запрос кидать в очередь и работать дальше не дожидаясь его результата, тот же rabbitMQ достаточно легко под это дело поднять можно. В любом случае надо закладывать вероятность того, что сторонний сервис будет недоступен или сломается